# Selector data is loaded correctly from the redux store, but not displayed by the calling page component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a page component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ScansOverview from './scansOverview';
import { loadPickingScans } from '../../actions';
import { pickingScansSelector } from '../../selectors';

class OrderPickingScansPage extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        const { loadPickingScans } = this.props;
        loadPickingScans(this.props.match.params.orderReference);
    }

    render() {
        const {pickingScans} = this.props;
        console.info("pickingScans", pickingScans);

        return (
            <div>
                <ScansOverview Scans={pickingScans}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
    const getPickingScansSelector = pickingScansSelector();
    return (state) => getPickingScansSelector(state);
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        loadPickingScans: () => dispatch(loadPickingScans())
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrderPickingScansPage);
```

That uses the `loadPickingScans` action to load the data it needs while consuming the `pickingScansSelector` selector to read it from store.

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const getPickingScans = (state) => state.scanning.pickingScans || [];

export const pickingScansSelector = () => createSelector(
    [getPickingScans],
    (pickingScans) => {
        console.info("pickingScans", pickingScans);

        return {
            pickingScans: [...pickingScans]
        }
    }
);
```

That `console.info` logs the following data:

[image]

Which is what I expect.

**The issue**

Is that the data received from the selector is not connected to the actual page, although it is correctly loaded. The `console.info("pickingScans", pickingScans)` line logs an empty array -> Array []. This means that the ScansOverview dumb component has nothing to display.

> What do I need to do / fix so that the selector data is correctly
>   passed to this.props?

I must be missing something stupid ...

**Update**

I added a debugger statement to both `mapStateToProps` and `componentDidMount`. `mapStateToProps` is hit first, then `componentDidMount`, the former is not hit again although the selector correctly loads the data required.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to fix your `mapStateToProps` function as follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const getPickingScansSelector = pickingScansSelector();
    return {
      pickingScans: getPickingScansSelector(state)
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm inclined to think it's only a difference in notation. It definitely (and sadly) did not fix the issue.

Comment: well first thing you were not passing the state param to `mapStateToProps` and I think you were returning a function not an object
These are the changes that I made: 1- the param 2- the returned object